# Ember.js: "this.$()" not working on component

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-components

Method `this.$()` is not working on a component. Following code:

**app/components/example-component.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  didRender() {
    Ember.$('body').click(this.exampleMethod).click();
  },
  exampleMethod() {
    console.log('"this" on exampleMethod():');
    console.log(this.$());
  },
});
```

Gets following error on web console:

```
TypeError: this.$ is not a function
```

How is `this.$()` to be used and how to get the jQuery element of a component?

Environment:

> DEBUG: -------------------------------
>   DEBUG: Ember             : 2.13.0
>   DEBUG: Ember Data        : 2.13.1
>   DEBUG: jQuery            : 3.2.1
>   DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.3.0
>   DEBUG: -------------------------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a component method `this` doesn't represent the component itself, but the element that has called the method.

If the component method is called by another component method, like `didRender()`, then `this` is the component, and `this.$()` returns the jQuery element of the component. So, this works:

**app/components/example-component.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  actions: {
    exampleAction() {
      console.log('"this" on exampleAction():');
      console.log(this.$());
    },
  },
  didRender() {
    this.send('exampleAction');
    console.log('"this" on didRender():');
    console.log(this.$());
    this.exampleMethod();
  },
  exampleMethod() {
    console.log('"this" on exampleMethod():');
    console.log(this.$());
  },
});
```

If the component method is called by some event attached to a DOM element, then `this` is the DOM element, and `this.$()` doesn't work. `Ember.$(this)` must be used instead:

**app/components/example-component.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  didRender() {
    console.log('"this" on didRender():');
    console.log(this.$());
    Ember.$('body').click(this.exampleMethod).click();
  },
  exampleMethod() {
    console.log('"this" on exampleMethod():');
    // console.log(this.$()); This doesn't work
    console.log(Ember.$(this));
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post, I wanted to get the exception in twiddle but in the logs it says undefined instead of raising error. See [my twiddle link](https://ember-twiddle.com/12207ea6634f82d0a91e39df43023c58?openFiles=components.example-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.example-component.hbs)

Comment: It's because of the init() method. If you use didRender() method, you'll get a different result. A right result indeed. Problem appears when the method is called by an event like Ember.$('body').click(this.exampleMethod).click(); 
I'm updating question and aswer to show it.